# BIg-Oh for reversing LinkedList in Java

Tags: java, big-o

Please advise what would be the Big-O in these two cases. I understand that the base case would be constant `O(1)`, but am confused how to compute for the rest and the recursion.

#### Case #1

```java
public ListNode reverse1(ListNode list) {
    if (list == null || list.next == null) {
        return list;
    }
    ListNode after = reverse(list.next);
    list.next.next = list;
    list.next = null;
    return after;
}
```

#### Case #2

```java
public ListNode reverse2(ListNode list) {
    if (list == null || list.next == null) {
        return list;
    }
    ListNode after = reverse2(list.next);
    ListNode temp = after;
    while (temp.next != null) {
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    temp.next = list;
    list.next = null;
    return after;
}
```

Comment: Case #1 is incorrect, but O(n) as the reversion visits every node in the list, and the function itself does just O(1) things. Case #2 walks the partial list every time (n/2) so is O(N²). Of course reversal can be done correctly in O(n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In your first case** the recursion gives:

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + c
```

where `T(n)` is the overall steps for n nodes, in order to reverse `n` nodes you just reverse `n-1` in `T(n-1)` and add the nth node by doing constant operations which cost `c` (constant value doesn't matter).

The above recursive relation is easy to see that leads to:

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + c = T(n-2) + 2c =...= nc = O(n)
```

**In your second case** the recursion gives:

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + n + c
```

That's because in order to reverse n nodes you reverse `n-1` in `T(n-1)` and you traverse the list in order to place the node at the end which cost n and constant operations which cost at most c (c doesn't matter).

The above recursive relation is easy to see that leads to:

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + n +c = T(n-2) + n + (n-1) + 2c =...= n(n-1)/2 +nc = O(n^2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Frank! This is extremely helpful. I am having difficulty wrapping my head around the difference/relationship between T(..) and O(...). , how to arrive at such calculations.  Would you mind clarifying if there is a simple way of thinking about this? Thanks again

Comment: Thank you so much again!  In the 2nd case, if given only 2 choices: T(N) = T(N-1) + O(1)  or T(N) = T(N-1) + O(N), which one would you choose?

Comment: Yes of course, We use T(..) to denote the total steps (use any letter you want but T is usually used) there is no standard way to find T(n) only by practicing, e.g  if you have a loop it might be easy, if you have a recursive relation like your question T(n) equals the T used for subproblems e.g T(n-1)+T(n-2) (if you break your problem into calculating with n-1,n-2)  or it could be anything based on the subproblems you calculate recursively, and also in order to find T(n) add whatever operation you do in each step so for example: T(n) = T(n-1) + c means that you break ...(to be continued)

Comment: your problem in calculating T(n-1) and some constant operations ...That's in general how to think in order to find T(n)..Now for finding big O depends on T(n) you already found. If you have a recursive relation T(n) you may find `Master Theorem` helpful in order to find big O, In your particular case it was easy since `T(n)=T(n-1)+c` can be easily computed by hand... In general big O is used to notate the asymptotic behavior, that's why constants doesn't matter.

Comment: For your second question I would definitely choose `T(N) = T(N-1) + O(N)` since you need O(n) steps as explained, in my explanation I wrote: `T(n) = T(n-1) + n + c` which can be written as  `T(N) = T(N-1) + O(N)` since `n+c is O(n)`,   if my answer solves your problem consider accepting it, glad to help!!

Comment: Thanks a lot again Frank, for answering my second question as well! Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

**Case #1a** *(Not an answer)*

For those that want to see (one version of) a clean recursive list reversal.
Especially without next.next.

```
public ListNode reverse1a(ListNode list) {
    return reverse1rec(list, null);
}

/**
 * Recursive reversal.
 * Following the technique of shifting (to-do part, done part).
 * @param list to be reversed (to-do).
 * @param reversed already reversed earlier (done).
 */
public ListNode reverse1rec(ListNode list, ListNode reversed) {
    if (list == null) {
        return reversed;
    }
    ListNode remaining = list.next;
    list.next = reversed;
    reversed = list; // For clarity.
    return reverse1rec(remaining, reversed);
}
```